# Detect which child was hover from parents onmouseover event

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-outputfield

I have made a custom record detail page of the custom object and used `lightning-output-field` to display the value of a lookup field. Now I want a feature that when I hover the mouse over the value of that field a popup get displayed, so I placed a `onmouseover` event on the `lightning-output-field` but even when I hover the field name of that field the pop up get displayed i.e. the pop up get visible if I hover anywhere on the `lightning-output-field` but I only want to display the popup when I hover the mouse on field value (there is `<a>` tag in which we have the value for the field).

So is there a way by which we can identify the mouse hover on which part of the `lightning-output-field` in lwc?

I used `event.target` but get no information that could help me.

code for reference

HTML :

```
<lightning-output-field class="demo" ref="outputField"
                                            value={recordId.Primary_Sales_Name__c}
                                            field-name="Primary_Sales_Name__c" onmouseover={handleFocusPrimarySales}>
```

JS :

```
handleFocusPrimarySales(event) {
    console.log('line 147 ',event.target);
}
```

Comment: You should ensure the event target exposes a value you can find useful.

Comment: @PhilW can you explain it bit more?

Comment: Ensure the child element exposes a value you can use, via an API property or method for example. Alternatively consider if you can use the `key` for the child.

Comment: Of course, you can control the events if you have a child component of your own (see [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-from-child-to-parent)). I.e. wrap the input so your new child component manages just the one input.

Comment: I am using `lightning-output-field` it has <a> tag in it which is not visible

Comment: I'm recommending you wrap the output field in your own component (if possible) that processes the event from its wrapped component. Since it wraps just the one component it knows what it is dealing with.